# Customizable Option: How do I show "Personalization Text" textbox only if "Personalization" dropdown is set to "YES"

Tags: magento2, product, products, customizable-options

**Magento2:**
While adding a product I want User to select "Personalization" (Dropdown: "YES/NO"), If "YES" "Personalization Text" (Textbox) will be shown.
Currently, I am doing this using Customizable Option while adding product and both "Personalization" and "Personalization Text" are compulsory now.

**Expected is:** 
If Personalization = YES then Personalization Text should be shown/enabled & Compulsory. 
If Personalization = NO then Personalization Text should be Hidden/Disabled. 
If Personalization = --Select Option-- then Personalization Text should be Hidden/Disabled.

From where shall I handle this?

Comment: Can someone please help on this?